# org-return modified - paste contents below the heading, indepentently from the cursor position

Tags: org-mode

In the following interesting config
https://www.gtrun.org/post/config/#alphapapa-unpackaged-dot-el-a-collection-of-useful-emacs-lisp-code-that-isn-t-substantial-enough-to-be-packaged
I found the command `(unpackaged/org-return-dwim)`. It works when the cursor is on the heading, so that the cursor moves to the end headings content.
I would like to make this command work in the heading itself, I managed to do it for two different cases for my custom paste in heading command:

a) When the cursor is on the heading

b) When the cursor is below the heading

Following code is used:

```
(evil-define-operator paste-in-prev-heading (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Delete preceding line(s)."
  :motion nil
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")
;; If count is nil or not a number
        (cond
          ((not (numberp count))
           (setq count 1) ) )

(org-previous-visible-heading count)
(unpackaged/org-return-dwim)
(evil-paste-before 1) )

(evil-define-operator paste-in-next-heading (beg end type register count yank-handler)
  "Delete preceding line(s)."
  :motion nil
  (interactive "<R><x><c><y>")

(unpackaged/org-return-dwim )
(evil-paste-after 1)
)
```

My question is, how can I combine the two cases into one? I need to somehow notice whether the cursor is on the heading or not in order to select either command made for the cursor on the heading or the command made for the cursor under the heading. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `org-at-heading-p` to determine whether you are currently on a heading or not. Perhaps better however, you can use `org-back-to-heading` unconditionally: then you are guaranteed to be at the beginning of the heading - that assumes that `unpackaged/org-return-dwim` does what you expect from there; if not, you might want to also do `org-end-of-line` to make sure that you are in a context where `unpackaged/org-return-dwim` *will* do the "right" thing.